# XPath for Workday

Tags: xpath, workday-api

I'm really new with XPath and would appreciate your expert advice!

```
<wd:Get_Workers_Response xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" wd:version="v24.1">
    <wd:Response_Data>
      <wd:Worker>
        <wd:Worker_Data>
          <wd:Employment_Data>                                                  
           <wd:Position_Data wd:Effective_Date="2022-04-17-07:00">
            <wd:Job_Classification_Summary_Data>
             <wd:Job_Classification_Reference wd:Descriptor="Some Value">
             <wd:ID wd:type="WID">6abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd2</wd:ID>                                                                                                        
             <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Reference_ID">Some_Value</wd:ID>                                                                                     
            </wd:Job_Classification_Reference>
            <wd:Job_Group_Reference wd:Descriptor="MIP">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Group_ID">JOB_CLASSIFICATION_GROUP_MIP</wd:ID>
           </wd:Job_Group_Reference>
          </wd:Job_Classification_Summary_Data>
         </wd:Position_Data>
        </wd:Employment_Data>
      </wd:Worker_Data>
     </wd:Worker>
    </wd:Response_Data>
</wd:Get_Workers_Response>
```

I'd like to get the value "Some_value" in
<wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Reference_ID">Some_Value</wd:ID>
where WID=6abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd2

Can you tell me the xpath for that?

Comment: please edit the question and show a [mcve] - a complete, valid XML including namespace declarations, etc.

Comment: @Arren, no, you still havent specified the namespace-uri to which the prefix `'wd:'` is associated!

Comment: Updated with your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you can declare a prefix for the used namespace use this XPath:

```
//wd:ID[@wd:type='WID' and text()='6abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd2']/following-sibling::wd:ID[1]/text()
```

Or as an faster alternative while the XPath is more explicit, use this XPath:

```
//wd:Job_Classification_Summary_Data/wd:Job_Classification_Reference[wd:ID[@type='WID']/text() = '6abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd2']]/wd:ID[@type='Job_Classification_Reference_ID']/text()
```

If you are not able do use a prefix use this XPath:

```
//*[local-name()='ID'][@*[local-name()='type' and .='WID'] and text()='6abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd2']/following-sibling::*[local-name()='ID'][1]/text()
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my code with the namespace.
I tested the XPath you provided and it looks like it's exactly what I needed.

Here's the XPath I came up with and it seems to work as well.  Would the XPath below make sense to a seasoned XPath writer? Or is it just a roundabout way to get to the text node?  
//*[wd:ID[@type='WID']/text() = '6abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd2']/ancestor::wd:Job_Classification_Summary_Data/wd:Job_Classification_Reference/wd:ID[@type='Job_Classification_Reference_ID']

Comment: It looks okay but somewhat of a detour. I will add an alternative in my answer that is more strait forward

Answer (score 1):

This XPath expression:

```
string(//wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Job_Classification_Reference_ID']/text())
```

when evaluated against the provided XML document (with added arbitrary namespace-uri for the prefix `'wd:'` to make it wellformed):

```
<wd:Response_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/xxx">
  <wd:Worker>
    <wd:Worker_Data>
      <wd:Employment_Data>
       <wd:Position_Data wd:Effective_Date="2022-04-17-07:00">
        <wd:Job_Classification_Summary_Data>
         <wd:Job_Classification_Reference wd:Descriptor="Some Value">
         <wd:ID wd:type="WID">6abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd2</wd:ID>
         <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Reference_ID">Some_Value</wd:ID>
        </wd:Job_Classification_Reference>
        <wd:Job_Group_Reference wd:Descriptor="MIP">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Group_ID">JOB_CLASSIFICATION_GROUP_MIP</wd:ID>
       </wd:Job_Group_Reference>
      </wd:Job_Classification_Summary_Data>
     </wd:Position_Data>
    </wd:Employment_Data>
  </wd:Worker_Data>
 </wd:Worker>
</wd:Response_Data>
```

Selects the string value of the wanted text node:

```
Some_Value
```

**Do note**:
In your     XPath   engine you need to register a `'wd:'` prefix and associate it with the `"urn:com.workday/xxx"` namespace.